# Angular generic pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I would like to write generic `pipe`. This is the `pipe` where I have written for data type `Category`

*order-by-category.ts*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from '../../models/Category';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';


@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByCategory',
})
export class OrderByCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Category[]): Category[] {
    return sortBy(value, (o: Category) => { return o.name; });
  }
}
```

*.html*

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let c of categorySortedList | orderByCategory">
      <ion-label>{{c.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio [value]="c.id" (ionSelect)="selectedCategory(c)"></ion-radio>
 </ion-item>
```

Now I need to write the same kind of `pipe`. But the `data type` is different.

Now it is like this:

```
 transform(value: BudgetGroup[]): BudgetGroup[] {
    return sortBy(value, (o: BudgetGroup) => { return o.name; });
  }
```

So I would like to use generic solution here rather than the same kind of 2 `pipes` and also I need to maintain `Typed pipe` too.

Comment: Would simply replacing `Category` with `{ name: string }` not work?

Comment: I didn't try anything here yet.Hope you put your suggestion as an answer with more details? @Rob

Comment: Well, before asking a question here, you most definitely *should* try some things yourself..

Comment: Actually, I have written above the `specific pipe`. After that, I don't know how to convert it as a `generic` one.@Rob

Comment: I cannot see any difference between your suggestion and the `any` (`no type`) here.Your thoughts? @Rob

Comment: Any allows any type, what I wrote before explicitly checks that the object has a member called 'name' of type 'string'.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear for me.Hope you'll show `code snippet` here. @Rob

Answer (score 21):

I'm just writing the same and found your question. The answer is quite obvious - generic function will work:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByName',
})
export class OrderByNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T extends {name: string}>(value: T[]): T[] {
    return value.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
      if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

The original type is kept and seen in templates

Comment: The template will complain when in string mode with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to clarify what @Rob has already pointed out, with code. You can generalize your pipe's `transform()` method to conform to a certain type that has a mandatory 'name' like this.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';

export interface NameModelForPipe {
 name: string; // forces the 'name' property
 [key: string]: any; // allows for basically another property of 'any' type
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByNameModel',
})
export class OrderByNameModelPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: NameModelForPipe[]): NameModelForPipe[] {
    return sortBy(value, (o: NameModelForPipe) => { return o.name; });
  }
}
```

If you don't want to declare an interface explicitly, you can specify it in-line,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { sortBy } from 'lodash';


@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByNameModel',
})
export class OrderByNameModelPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: { name: string; [key: string]: any; }[]): { name: string; [key: string]: any; }[] {
    return sortBy(value, (o: { name: string; [key: string]: any; }) => { return o.name; });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a similar question here : [A way to cast variables in template to multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101344/a-way-to-cast-variables-in-template-to-multiple-types) and since I went trough this post like 10 times when searching online, I would like to post a hacky solution here too.

> I made the following simple pipe :
>
> ```
> @Pipe({   name: 'toType',   pure: true, }) export class ToTypePipe
> implements PipeTransform {   transform<T>(value: unknown, _: T): T {
>     return value as T;   } }
> ```
>
> You can call it like
>
> `value | toType: Animal.DOG`
>
> value can be anything of `Animal` but we just cast is as one of the
> value, so the compiler consider it ok to use it and do not complain.
>
> **IT IS NOT SAFE AND KIND OF REMOVE THE PURPOSE OF STRICT MODE.**
>
> But, it allow to do some workaround and make some very simple cast
> easy. like in this case :
>
> ````
> [cdkColumnDef]="columns.name.def">   <td class="align-items-center p-4
> w-80" cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">  ```
>
> `*cdkCellDef="let element"` this IS an `Animal` but angular template
> do not allow us to have the correct typing, so in this case `let
> element | typeOf: Animal.DOG` should be completely safe
> ````