# A way to cast variables in template to multiple types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app in angular where I set

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```

So every input / output is not type checked.

It is good for most of the app, but I have some app input like (here I show select, but I also have a simple `app-input` that works the same) :

`.html`

```
      <app-select
        [useSearch]="true"
        [formControlName]="'country'"
        (valueChange)="setSelectedCountry($event)" <=== $event is of type unknown
      >
        <app-option
          *ngFor="let country of locations$ | async"
          [name]="'COUNTRIES.' + country.code | translate"
          [value]="country.code" <=== this is of type Country
        ></app-option>
      </app-select>
```

`.ts`

```
  setSelectedCountry(code: Country) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadLocationRequest({ payload: { code } }));
    this.selectedLocation$ = this.store.pipe(select(getLocationByCode(), { code }));
  }
```

in the above, since I use my `app-select` for multiple selector with various value, it is type :

```
  @Input()
  get value(): unknown | unknown[] {
    return this.pValue;
  }
  set value(newValue: unknown | unknown[]) {
    if (newValue !== this.pValue) {
      this.pValue = newValue;
      this.writeValue(newValue);
    }
  }
```

Now, There is 2 solutions I see,

1. I do not use the ngModel like this `[(value)]="country"` and I make a method that typecheck in all my components that use a select:
2. I create a type for every type of value my select use and cast to it.

But I would like to have something easier for those case only.

Is it possible to pass a Generic type to a component via input or something, so that it return a type of the Generic I passed  ?
like (ex : `<app-select<string>>`)

Is it possible to make a pipe that cast a to a generic value ? without having to make a pipe for each type ? `string` `number` etc... ?

Is it possible to ignore certain checks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried multiple thing, and I came with a hacky way, I do not really recommend, unless in some special case (a bit like the $any()).

**The correct way would be :**

a Pipe for each unknown type, so that inside the type you can do some types check for ex

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { Gender } from '@app/__generated__/globalTypes'

@Pipe({
  name: 'toAnimal',
  pure: true,
})
export class ToAnimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: unknown): Animal {
    return typeof value === "string" && Object.keys(Animal).includes(value) ? 
              value as Animal : 
              Animal.DOG // Default value just use anything you want.
  }
}
```

**The hacky way :**

I made the following simple pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toType',
  pure: true,
})
export class ToTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: unknown, _: T): T {
    return value as T;
  }
}
```

You can call it like

```
 value | toType: Animal.DOG
```

value can be anything of `Animal` but we just cast is as one of the value, so the compiler consider it ok to use it and do not complain.

**IT IS NOT SAFE AND KIND OF REMOVE THE PURPOSE OF STRICT MODE.**

But, it allow to do some workaround and make some very simple cast easy. like in this case :

```
<table [dataSource]="animals"> <=== Array<Animal>
 <ng-container [cdkColumnDef]="columns.name.def">
  <td class="align-items-center p-4 w-80" cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">
```

`*cdkCellDef="let element"` this IS an `Animal` but angular template do not allow us to have the correct typing, so in this case `let element | typeOf: Animal.DOG` should be completely safe